# onclick function not being called? - no errors

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, event-handling, javascript-objects

I'm defining a class `Session` that is created for every new session.

In `window.onload`, the Session object has a mouse click event listener , on click, it fires the handler and 1. checks if anchor tag was clicked and saves href 2. saves the x and y of mouse click.

**The problem:** *The function user.onclick is not working. Doesn't call the anchorLinkClickHandler(); OR window.addEventListener i.e. the click event handler that saves x and y. NO ERRORS. I think there is a syntactical issue with the below code.. don't know what. Ideas?*

**As shown (in window.onload):**

```
var user = new UserSession('001');

user.onclick = function(event) {

// check if an anchor tag link is clicked, if so, save the href.
        user.aTagHref = anchorLinkClickHandler();

        // CLICK event listener - save the x and  y of mouse click
        window.addEventListener("load", function(event){    
            document.body.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
        });
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
  function UserSession(campaignId) {
  this.campaignId = campaignId;
  var aTagHref = aTagHref;

  this.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  };

  // get the position of click - Event Listener Function
  this.getPosition = function(el) {
          var xPosition = 0;
          var yPosition = 0;
         
          while (el) {
            if (el.nodeName == "BODY") {
              // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
              var xScrollPos = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
              var yScrollPos = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
         
              xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - xScrollPos + el.clientLeft);
              yPosition += (el.offsetTop - yScrollPos + el.clientTop);
            } else {
              xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
              yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop)
            }
         
            el = el.offsetParent;
          }
          return {
            x: xPosition,
            y: yPosition,
            a: "hahah",
          };
    };

    // On click handler
    this.handleClick = function(event) {
        // Return the current element clicked on
        var el = event.currentTarget;
        // Return the offset values of the element clicked on   
        var relOffsetValues = getPosition(el);


        // Find the true value of x and y by adding the offset and the to clicked value of x and y
        var realValueX = (relOffsetValues.x + event.clientX );
        var realValueY = (relOffsetValues.y + event.clientY);

        // display the x and y of the mouse click
        alert("Clicks x:" + realValueX + ", y:" + realValueY);
        // alert("clientx:" + event.clientX + ", real valie:" + realValueX);
    }

    // On click ANCHOR TAGS SAVE THEM
    // Anchor Tags - Capture the href of the link clicked
    this.anchorLinkClickHandler = function() {
        var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

        for (var i = aTags.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            aTags[i].onclick = function() {
            aTagHref[i] = this.getAttribute("href");
                alert(aTagHref);
            };
        }
    }

 // END OF CLASS 
}
```

**Window.onload function (where everything is called)**

window.onload = function() {

```
var user = new UserSession('001');

user.onclick = function(event) {
    // check if an anchor tag link is clicked, if so, save the href.
        user.aTagHref = anchorLinkClickHandler();

        // CLICK event listener - save the x and  y of mouse click
        window.addEventListener("load", function(event){    
            document.body.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
        });
}

    // SCROLL Event Listener
    // Get the x and y of the scroll
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
         // document.getScroll= function(){
             var sx, sy;
             if(window.pageYOffset!= undefined){
                sx = pageXOffset;
                sy = pageYOffset;
                 console.log(sx +" if " + sy);
              // return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
             }
             else{
               var d= document, r= d.documentElement, b= d.body;
              sx= r.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft || 0;
              sy= r.scrollTop || b.scrollTop || 0;
              console.log(sx +" else " + sy);
              // return [sx, sy];
             }
        // }
    });
};
```

Comment: You set `user.onclick = function(event) { ... }` at the beginning of your code, and then never call that function.

Comment: @gyre - perhaps the OP thinks `onclick` is in some way a special property - it is ... on HTMLElements, but has no super powers on regular objects

Comment: @JaromandaX Good point. Worth mentioning that `user` is an instance of the `UserSession` custom class and is thus a  POJO (Plain Ol' JavaScript Object).

Comment: `onClick` is a `DOM` event, thus you should only attach it to `DOM` elements

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick to better understand.

> The click event is raised when the user clicks on an element. The click event will occur after the mousedown and mouseup events.

You will have to create a HTML element first and when that element is clicked you have to execute a function that does all the actions you want.

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("#btn").onclick = function(event) {
 // do things here
}
```